# How do I make Eclipse's HTML text editor highlight one word on Shif+Alt+Left (or Right)?

Tags: eclipse

On every other editor in the universe, that key sequence would highlight the next word.  But in the Eclipse HTML editor it highlights the entire page.  This is driving me insane, why does this one text editor out of all of the Eclipse packages break this convention?  I'm doing some work in the middle of a huge file and I'm trying to highlight one word, and then all of a sudden I've highlighted the whole file and the focus has jumped to the top of the file and I can't even find my place again.

Is there a way to adjust this behavior?  Is there a better option for an HTML editor for Eclipse?

Comment: Less ranty, more questionny.

Comment: Actually in most editors, Shift+CTRL+Arrow would select a word.  Alt is not Ctrl.

Comment: Just to add to CarlF's comment, Shift+Ctrl+Arrow does have this expected behavior in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to preferences, General, Keys : Select Previous Element (list item name)

The preference for shift-alt-left should be under "Select Previous Element", but may be different for the precise file type you are editing, or have been changed by a plug-in you installed, perhaps?

Doing a search for "page" I certainly don't see that; I have the default settings.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the problem, it seems that the HTML editor even has a weird definition of what the "next word" actually is and may mean it is a tag.  In the middle of JavaScript in HTML the tag is the start of the <script> tag.

Comment: Actually this fixed the problem!  Made a few small mistakes the first time!  Thanks.  It helped fix a really frustrating problem.